# Ironjacamar deployment attribute

Tags: wildfly, datasource, jca, ironjacamar

I have a very large app which I'm trying to port to wildfly 12 from jboss 5. I know very little about the app.

At present I'm seeing this error in the wildfly logs

> 07:37:49,040 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener]
>   (default task-4) IJ000315: Pool xyz has 1 active handles

This [page](http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/roadto12/txtracking.html) gives some indication of what causes the error and recommends setting a particular *deployment attribute* to help diagnose the problem.

My question is, in this context what is a deployment attribute and how to I set one?

The pool xyz mentioned in the error above is associated with a JDBC data source. I have no idea what ironjacamar is, or why it's getting involved in this app, so keep it simple.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here, but what is meant by a *deployment attribute* is an XML attribute on the deployment descriptor, like this

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc.config.dataSource" pool-name="xyz" use-java-context="false" 
    tracking="true">
```

Might be obvious to most, but not to me.

Answer (score 0):

5 years question. But here's the solution: Set "tracking" atribute to false.

```
  <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/MGEDS" pool-name="MGEDS" enabled="true"
use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true" tracking="false">
```